# Is it possible to create a line graph in r, where the colour of the line changes at a specific point

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm currently working on forecasts with different models and i was wondering if it is possible to create a line graph in R (i'm currently working with ggplot2, but i'd gladly consider other packages) that has one colour for the actual values and afterwards changes the colour to highlight how the forecast developed?
Thanks in advance!

edit: Thank you for your suggestions but i used a different approach and plotted the forecast together with the real data in one plot which visualizes it better imo

Comment: what i can suggest you is to simply use two seperate lines. i.e. one in green starting and ending where you have actual values, and a second one i.e. in red where your forecast starts. its a little hacky, but it should work

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What does your graphing code look like so far?

Comment: Just use `color` in `aes`. The only slightly non-trivial bit will be to replicate the connection point with both colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's typically done by graphing two lines of different colors, but they meet at a point so there is an illusion that there is only one line.